# Shared Constants Across Elixir Applications

Tags: elixir

What's the best way to keep constants that could be shared across different elixir applications?

In my case, I have shorthands for different types of payments in the system.
e.g.

```
CreditCard => "ccd", CashOnDelivery => "cod"
```

etc. I want to keep these values shared across applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Erlang provides two magical functions, [`binary_to_term/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#binary_to_term-1) and [`term_to_binary/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#term_to_binary-1).

Construct your own map (**do not use Capitalized symbols for keys**, while they are indeed atoms they are reserved for module names. They are not constants by any mean.)

```
shared_constants = %{credit_card: "ccd", cash_on_delivery: "cod"}
```

and store it into some file in the top-level directory:

```
File.write!("path/to/file", :erlang.term_to_binary(shared_constants))
```

Once done, get an access to this map from anywhere:

```
shared_constants =
  "path/to/file"
  |> File.read!()
  |> :erlang.binary_to_term()
```

and access values as:

```
shared_constants.credit_card
#⇒ "ccd"
```

---

*Sidenote:* FWIW, Joe Armstrong answering the question “[What do you like the most about Erlang/OTP?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/erlang-programming/Ig9BG_BikVE/ApPW-RrzUg8J)”:

[image]

Comment: You can also use [Poison][1] library to store your map in a json file, with `Poison.encode!` and `Poison.decode!`. If you have an opinion on this variant, I would be interested to read it.
 
   [1]: https://github.com/devinus/poison

Comment: @NathanRipert `binary_to_term/1` is blazingly fast and does not require any 3rd party library. I see absolutely no reason to use JSON here. BTW, the best JSON parser nowadays is https://github.com/michalmuskala/jason by Michał Muskała, one of Elixir core team members. Also, JSON does not support tuples serialization, while `binary_to_term/1` does.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
defmodule Constants do
  def credit_card, do: "ccd"
  def cash_on_delivery, do: "cod"
end
```

Application directory:

```
~/elixir_programs$ tree app1

app1
├── README.md
├── _build
│   └── dev
│       └── lib
│           └── app1
│               ├── consolidated
│               │   ├── Elixir.Collectable.beam
│               │   ├── Elixir.Enumerable.beam
│               │   ├── Elixir.IEx.Info.beam
│               │   ├── Elixir.Inspect.beam
│               │   ├── Elixir.List.Chars.beam
│               │   └── Elixir.String.Chars.beam
│               └── ebin
│                   ├── Elixir.App1.beam
│                   ├── Elixir.Constants.beam
│                   └── app1.app
├── config
│   └── config.exs
├── lib
│   ├── app1.ex
│   └── constants.ex
├── mix.exs
└── test
    ├── app1_test.exs
    └── test_helper.exs

9 directories, 16 files
```

app1.ex:

```
defmodule App1 do
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for App1.
  """

  @doc """
  Hello world.

  ## Examples

      iex> App1.hello
      :world

  """
  def hello do
    IO.puts "Hello #{Constants.credit_card}"
  end
end
```

And:

```
~/elixir_programs/app1$ mix compile
Compiling 2 files (.ex)
Generated app1 app

~/elixir_programs/app1$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> App1.hello
Hello ccd
:ok

iex(2)>
```

If you don't want to have to write the prefix "Constants" all the time, then you can import the Constants module:

```
defmodule App1 do
  @moduledoc """
  Documentation for App1.
  """

  @doc """
  Hello world.

  ## Examples

      iex> App1.hello
      :world

  """
  import Constants
  def hello do
    IO.puts "Hello #{credit_card()}"  #...but need the trailing parentheses
  end
end
```

Comment: _Yeah, one also might create an application backed by a `GenServer` storing these constants._ If you want to propose to create a module, the module should declare `__using__/1` macro basically exposing constants as module attributes `@credit_card` and `@cash_on_delivery` and the constants will be available by `use MyConstants` without polluting the namespace with redundant functions.